# How to convert .bat(windows) to .sh file (ubuntu)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, ubuntu, sh

I'm trying to start a java application in ubuntu with run.sh just like i would on windows with run.bat but it's not working. Everything is compiled with eclipse on windows.
My original .bat code is (working on windows):

```
@title BDK
@echo off
java -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -cp bin;lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;lib/netty-3.5.2.Final.jar;lib/FileStore.jar;lib/GTLVote.jar com.rs.Launcher
pause
```

The code i have in my run.sh:

```
java -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -cp bin;lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;lib/netty-3.5.2.Final.jar;lib/FileStore.jar;lib/GTLVote.jar com.rs.Launcher
```

Which gives me this error:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.rs.Launcher

Java version on Ubuntu: JDK 7 (don't know how to install 8 because i'm new to ubuntu)
Java version on Windows: JDK 8

Thanks in advance!
BDK

Answer (score 0):

In your -cp argument in your run.sh command you have semi-colons where you should have colons.  So, basically, your classpath wasn't being loaded at all.

Comment: Thanks, but editing it still gives me this error:
[code]Error: Could not find or load main class com.rs.Launcher
[/code]

This is my current code:
[code]java -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -cp /bin:/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar:/lib/netty3.5.2.Fin$.2.Final.jar:/lib/FileStore.jar:/lib/GTLVote.jar com.rs.Launcher
[/code]

**why are my code tags not working

Comment: You need to be more careful.  When you put directories in your classpath, if they are not included in the path, then you need to put "./bin:" instead of "bin:", etc.   The issue you are having has nothing to do with Java and everything to do with referencing paths on Unix.  Windows automatically puts the current directory in the path unlike Linux (unless you configure it that way on purpose).

Comment: So it would become: [code]
java -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -cp ./bin:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar:lib/netty-3.5.2.Final.jar:lib/FileStore.jar:lib/GTLVote.jar com.rs.Launcher
[/code]

This still gives me the same error:
Error: Could not find or load main class com.rs.Launcher

Sorry for how unskilled i am at ubuntu, i never used it before and using google didn't help.

Comment: not quite.  you also need to do it on "./lib"  etc.  Please do more research on Unix paths.